# Publishing a npm package with custom scope in GitHub Packages

Tags: github, npm, github-packages

We are trying to publish a custom scoped package to GitHub Packages.

For example `@foo/bar`

The problem is that `@foo` is not the GitHub owner and this seems to be a requirement in the `name` in package.json.

This is what our `package.json` looks like:

```
{
  "name": "@foo/bar",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/OWNER"
  }
}
```

When we try this we get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://npm.pkg.github.com/OWNER/@foo%2fbar - Permission not_found: owner not found
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
npm ERR! 403 on a server you do not have access to.
```

Even though we specify the owner on the registry URL it says owner not found.

I am wondering if publishing a custom scoped package is supported or not.

Anyone has come across this issue?

Thanks!